# Log4jv2 Remove square brackets around NDC "%x"

Tags: log4j2

I would like to remove the square brackets around the Nested Diagnostic Context.
This is the current pattern I have, is there a way to remove the square brackets from output?

```
#Console Appender
appender.console.name=STDOUT
appender.console.type=Console
appender.console.layout.type=PatternLayout
appender.console.layout.pattern=%d{yyyyMMdd HHmmss.SSS} %-5p [%-8.8t] %-15.15c{1} %3x %m%n
```

%3x outputs [content], I would like just content.

Answer (score 1):

you can use replace function like this:

```
    %d{yyyyMMdd HHmmss.SSS} %-5p [%-8.8t] %-15.15c{1} %replace{%3x}{\[\]}{  } %m%n
```

See https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/layouts.html#PatternLayout